# Use rsync to copy only hidden files

Tags: macos, rsync

I want to back up all the hidden files and directories in my homedir using rsync, but not the non-hidden files and directories.

For example, given this directory listing:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 sophie  sophie  238 31 Mar 08:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 sophie  sophie  510 31 Mar 08:14 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 sophie  sophie    4 31 Mar 08:12 .foo
drwxr-xr-x   3 sophie  sophie  102 31 Mar 08:45 .hiddendir
drwxr-xr-x   4 sophie  sophie  136 31 Mar 08:13 VisibleDirectory
-rw-r--r--   1 sophie  sophie    9 31 Mar 08:13 VisibleFile
```

I want to back up .foo, .hiddendir, and all the contents of .hiddendir whether they are hidden or not. I don't want to back up VisibleDirectory or VisibleFile.

All the incantations I have come up with back up ".", and therefore all its contents including VisibleFile and VisibleDirectory, and I can't figure out how to exclude it. Please help!

I'm using Mac OS X 10.5.6 (Leopard) and rsync version 2.6.9 protocol version 29.

Comment: Why doesn't `--exclude='.' --exclude='..'` work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A common pattern to match the hidden items is `.[^.]*`

```
rsync -a ~/.[^.]* /path/to/backup
```

This copies all files starting with a single dot. Note that it doesn't include files starting with more than one dot.

Comment: Very helpful. I can also use `rsync -a source/[^.]* dest/` to sync all the non-hidden files, excluding entries such as `.git`.

Answer (score 12):

It's usually ".??*" to make sure you don't copy "." and ".."

(What if you had a file that was just ".a" ?)

Comment: Hey Martin, I don't understand why `./.?` matches `./..`. I read the doc here https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm and it says that `?` replaces `a-z,0-9` so why does it match with `.`?
Test with: `for f in ./.?; do echo $f; done`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried incarnations like ./.*?

Could you copy the hidden files to a temp directory, back up the temp directory, then remove it?